# How to create Elastic Beanstalk instance from s3 bucket in the aws-sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an elastic beanstalk instance from the aws javascript sdk and want the code source to come from an s3 bucket. I can see you can do this via the web interface but can't figure it out via the sdk.

so far I have the following which creates a new environment (application already exists at this point) but the env has no source code to run.

```
const elasticBeanstalkClient = new ElasticBeanstalkClient({ 
  region: "eu-west-2",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: awsAccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: awsAccessKeySecret
  } 
});

const createEnvironmentCommand = new CreateEnvironmentCommand({
  ApplicationName: applicationName,
  EnvironmentName: environmentName,
  SolutionStackName: "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.4.2 running Node.js 14",
  VersionLabel: versionLabel
})

return elasticBeanstalkClient.send(createEnvironmentCommand);
```

`CreateEnvironmentCommand` doesn't seem to have a source value that I can see. How am I supposed to tell the environment to be created from an s3 source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see you can do this via the web interface but can't figure it out via the sdk.

EB console does a lot of things in the background to make it seem you can do it. With CDK you have to do everything by yourself. This means you have to [createApplicationVersion](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/elasticbeanstalk/ElasticBeanstalkClient.html#createApplicationVersion-java.util.function.Consumer-) first. When you do this, you can specify S3 location.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. So I have to call CreateEnvironmentCommand and then call createApplicationVersion? Do you know if there is then another method I have to call to link the application to that environment or do I need to do it by passing some value to the `createApplicationVersion`?

Comment: @Stretch0 When you create `CreateApplicationVersionRequest` you specify `versionLabel`. Then in your `CreateEnvironmentCommand` you can reference the label.

Comment: Perfect, that's done the trick. Thanks for your help @Marcin